# Why does Firefox screw up my contenteditable element's text and placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a program where you can drag widgets around. It is well on chrome, but Firefox screws up the text and removes the placeholder text when I type and delete the text. What could be causing this?

Chrome:
[image: Chrome version image]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox version image].

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="note" @mousedown.left="e => draggable && moveDown(e)">
    <div class="content"> 
        <div class="note-body" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Write something...">{{note.body}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resizer" @mousedown.left="resizeDown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Comment: What you've posted is not HTML. `@mousedown.left=` is not HTML.

Comment: I'm guessing this is `vue`; added tag (can remove if it's incorrect)

Comment: Also, why are you using `contenteditable` instead of a restyled `<textarea>`? There are many issues with `contenteditable` and it's generally a good idea to avoid it.

Comment: @Dai, I want to be able to allow the user to edit the text if the user selects (click) on the note, and prevent the user from editing the text if they don't select the note.

Comment: @xNastalgia Just use a restyled `<textarea>` or `<input type="text" />`. Though I'm unsure why you say "prevent the user from editing the text if they don't select the note" - how can a user edit text *without* selecting or activating it first anyway?

Comment: @Dai, so I took your advice on using `<textarea>` and it really is much better than contenteditable. To clarify what I meant before, my widget is draggable and right now when the user drags, the user can edit the text while they are dragging. I do not want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment saying that `<textarea>` is an improvement, but you want to prevent the textarea from being activated/focused/selectable until the user clicks on the element, use a script to toggle `HTMLTextAreaElement.readonly` when the container is clicked and re-set it on `HTMLTextAreaElement.blur`. In Vanilla JS it would be like this:

```
<div class="note" @mousedown.left="e => draggable && moveDown(e)">
    <div class="content"> 
        <textarea class="note-body" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Write something">{{note.body}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="resizer" @mousedown.left="resizeDown"></div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
// Run this after the DOM is initialized. I don't know how you'd integrate this with Vue, however:

const tas = document.querySelectorAll( 'div.note textarea' );
for( const ta of tas ) {
    ta.addEventListener( 'blur', e => e.currentTarget.readonly = true );
}

const notes = document.querySelectorAll( 'div.note' );
for( const n of notes ) {
    n.addEventListener( 'click', e => {
        const ta = e.currentTarget.querySelector( 'textarea' );
        ta.readonly = false;
    } );
} 
</script>
```